# CasperJS & Object

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to create an `article` object constructor that holds attributes such as document title, author etc, and use create instances of the object based on different URL's I pass to it. In the below example `this.articleText` should return an array of strings, but it returns nothing.

This is contrast to `this.headlineText`, which returns the string `hello`, as expected.

Given this difference, I suspect the root cause of the problem is the `document` object being used in the constructor. There are no errors thrown in the output, however, so how should I resolve this?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
(There are no problems with the css selector itself; if I use a function to get the article string then this seems to work. The problem is when trying to use an object to parse data)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

function article(title, url) {
    this.headlineText = title;
    this.urlString = url;
    var query = document.querySelectorAll("[itemprop='articleBody']");

    this.articleText = Array.prototype.map.call(query, function (e) {
        return e.innerText;
    });
}


casper.start("http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/economy/20150625-OYT1T50136.html" ,     function() {
    this.test.assertExists({
        type: 'css',
        path: '[itemprop="articleBody"]'
    }, 'Article Exists');
});


casper.run(function() {
    var test1 = new article("hello","http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/economy/20150625-OYT1T50136.html");

    console.log("HEADLINE==");
    console.log(test1.headlineText); // returns "hello"

    console.log("ARTICLE == ");
    console.log(test1.articleText); // returns nothing

    this.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is misunderstanding on how you can access document object of the page.
You must use evaluate, cause all page calls are executed in sandbox:

[CasperJS evaluate()](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)

So you will have to call evaluate, and return from it your querySelectorAll, and then passed that one to your function :)

Good luck

Comment: Yes - the structure of the program is completely unlike selenium which is causing me the headache... I've rewritten this to call the evaluate function within casper.then( function(){...});

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to run javascript specific code you have to run it using `evaluate` function,which are executed in a sandbox.

You want to write something like this

```
casper.then(function() {
        var a = this.evaluate(article(title, url),{title:'hello',url:'url'});
});
```